# Is the iPod touch 4th generation good as a testing device

Tags: iphone, ipad, ipod-touch

I am planing to get iPod touch 4th generation 8GB to test my apps on it, as it has the same memory as the iPhone 3Gs (256MB) but speed and reselution as the iPhone 4 plus 3-axis gyroscope, my qustion is with todays top line devices (iPhone 4s & iPad2)  is the iPod touch 4 can be considered as lowest specification to target? I know that I should have several deferent devices laying around but for now I just need to get the first one, what would you advice me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

iPod is a good test device but it does not have A-GPS, neither you can test for Call APIs, neither you can check SMS APIs at some instances you'll find yourself blocked during testing. I do have a 3GS,4, 4s abd iPod touch. I myself have faced this condition many times so if you have any funding issue and you want to get the lowest test device with OS5, you must get iPhone 3GS at least which will give you full featured testing facility and you can test with all APIs in the apple's developer plate.!!!

Answer (score 1):

The iPod Touch 4G has about the same performance as an iPhone 4. So if you don't want to target the iPhone 3GS or if you don't care whether your app will run smoothly on iPhone 3GS then the iPod Touch 4G is a good testing device. However, the iPhone 3GS is still being sold so you might want to target that (or use an iPod Touch 3G which has similar performance but is cheaper). If you want to target iPhone 3GS/iPod Touch 3G you might also want test with a retina device as these are "standard" now.